# Minimal number of pairwise signals (mutexes) to follow a schedule

Tags: ai, simulations, graph, collision-avoidance

For a factory simulation, NPCs walk a path and stop in between to do things in work areas.
My task is to find the best work schedule. The NPCs can of course collide with each other on their way.
This must be prevented. For this, a collision area can be calculated beforehand (a simple box). There the NPCs "can" collide,
but they do not have to. Each waypoint of the NPCs has a predetermined time, but it can be longer (if the NPC is stopped by an obstacle).
The API of the simulation has the following limitations:

1. A collision box can only be calculated pairwise (NPC A <-> NPC B).
2. NPCs can only communticate pairwise (NPC A -> B or B -> A).
3. Communication happens with `Enter(int id)` (similiar to `mutex[id]->aquire()`) and `Exit(int id)` (similar to `mutex[id]->release()`) calls. I call them "signals".

First I created a simple graph where the waypoints with the times are inserted.
Then I create connections between the NPCs, if a path is in a collision area, to find a collision-free
topological sorting (without deadlock). This works well so far.
[The graph looks like this (collision area is marked red, found ordering is first C then A then B).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y95u8.png)
Only the generation of signals is my problem.

I can't create a global "index" that indicates which NPC's turn it is. NPC A has no idea about the signals between NPC B and C.
Nevertheless, the sequence should be strictly followed, even if the path of an NPC should be delayed.
Also, the number of signals should be as minimal as possible (since there is only a limited number).

The problems in short:

1. How can I keep the order of a schedule if only pairwise communication between NPCs is possible?
2. What is the lowest number of "signals" (or mutexes) needed?

If there is already a name for this problem, I haven't found it yet and would be grateful for this information as well.